# Subset data starting with... in R

Tags: r, subset

I want to subset a data frame to only keep lines (samples) that one of the column value starts with "GC" in `R`. Here's an example:

```
Species A Species B Species C SYTD Lat  Long
1         5         0         IS14 47.5 -55.4
2         2         1         IS15 47.5 -55.3
0         1         4         GC14 47.6 -55.3
3         2         3         GC15 47.6 -55.2
```

How to keep all columns but only lines which "SYTD" starts with "GC"?

Comment: for a data.frame named df, use `df[grepl("^GC", df$SYTD),]`

Comment: Yes it works well thanks. Sorry for the duplicate, I searched for a while but couldn't find the proper answer.